# Wandb website for Huggingface Trainer shows plots and logs only for the first model

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, wandb

I am finetuning multiple models using for loop as follows.

```
for file in os.listdir(args.data_dir):
    finetune(args, file)
```

BUT `wandb` website shows plots and logs only for the first file i.e., `file1` in `data_dir` although it is training and saving models for other files. It feels very strange behavior.

```
wandb: Synced bertweet-base-finetuned-file1: https://wandb.ai/***/huggingface/runs/***
```

This is a small snippet of **finetuning** code with Huggingface:

```
def finetune(args, file):
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=f'{model_name}-finetuned-{file}',
        overwrite_output_dir=True,
        evaluation_strategy='no',
        num_train_epochs=args.epochs,
        learning_rate=args.lr,
        weight_decay=args.decay,
        per_device_train_batch_size=args.batch_size,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=args.batch_size,
        fp16=True, # mixed-precision training to boost speed
        save_strategy='no',
        seed=args.seed,
        dataloader_num_workers=4,
    )

    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=tokenized_dataset['train'],
        eval_dataset=None,
        data_collator=data_collator,
    )
    trainer.train()
    trainer.save_model()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wandb.init(reinit=True)` and `run.finish()` helped me to log the models **separately** on wandb website.

The working code looks like below:

```
for file in os.listdir(args.data_dir):
    finetune(args, file)

import wandb
def finetune(args, file):
    run = wandb.init(reinit=True)
    ...
    run.finish()
```

Reference: https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/launch#how-do-i-launch-multiple-runs-from-one-script

Answer (score 2):

Hey I work at Weights & Biases. My first guess is that you have to call `wandb.finish()` at the end of your `finetune` function. This will close the wandb process. Then when you start a new iteration, a new wandb process should be spun up.

If you would like to log additional config data that isn't logged by the W&B integration in the Trainer you can always call `wandb.init` before kicking off your training, see [wandb.init docs here](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/track/launch) and log to that. The Trainer should pick up that there is already a wandb process running and so will just log to that process instead of spinning up a new one.

```
def finetune():
  config = {'my-config-thing1':44, 'my-config-thing12':'cats'}

  wandb.init(project='my-project-name', config=config, ...)


  .... # Your Hugging Face code here


  wandb.finish()
```

Comment: Didn't try this, maybe this will also work. But this gave me the pointer to my solution.